replace only certain fields of std::filesystem::path
I have an original std::filesystem::path object that is defined by the user and contains some formatters like:
"%iy/%im/%id/%H/%M/asdf/filename_d02_%y-%m-%d"

Now I walk through all the path components, replace the formatters one by one and append the path component to a newly created std::filesystem::path object. However here is the problem: I want the three root-associated fields
root path
root name
root directory

to stay the same. So what I did is this:
// Copy root_name, root_path, and root_directory if present
if (!original_path.root_name().empty()) {
    new_path = original_path.root_name();
}
if (!original_path.root_path().empty()) {
    new_path /= original_path.root_path();
}
if (!original_path.root_directory().empty()) {
    new_path /= original_path.root_directory();
}

But this looks cumbersome and overly verbose. Is there a way to do it where I can just modify the copy of the old path, e.g. altering the relative path field? I can't see how to do it since relative_path is const (no manipulation).

Convert to a string, do a regex replace? And then make a new path object?

these are substituted by strftime not by regex though. Also I would have to escape everything first. And then consider the bad properties of std::regex, I would have to add the cpre library but we don't have that in our production codebase yet. Seems more cumbersome to me.

I general I understand the problem, but when I try grasp details I'm confused. I see example of "user path pattern" which looks relative and you are expressing something about "original_path" and conserving root path/name/directory. How this is related to path pattern user provides? Is your problem related to Windows paths?
Can you express your problem in form of unit test? This is the best form of MCVE.

Offtopic: what is this %iy %im %id? Other stuff is clearly related to date/time elements, but those three with i prefix I can't to connect to anything.

I've implemented path time pattern (implementation is surprising simple and cool - literally just two lines of code), but after that I even more have no clue what is your actual problem. Looks like first part of your question. is poorly related to second. Please use my link as starting point, to provide [mcve] with test showing what is the problem you are struggling with.

@MarekR The formatting part is taken care of. I'm only dealing with the intricacies of std::filesystem::path. I want to basically recreate the old path but with the substitutions, but for that the root dir, root path and root name need to stay the same.
